# Integrating XUL with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml, firefox-addon, xul

Is it possible to integrate XUL with PHP, just like we do with HTML and PHP? If yes, what do I need to do in order to make this work?

What do I need to do to stop my server from trying to serve the XUL as plain text or HTML?

Additionally, if you have a good resource or tutorial for understanding how to do this that would be awesome!

Comment: What does XUL have to do with PHP?

Comment: If you open an xul file in Firefox your Firefox will yell that this is not possible for security reasons.

Comment: @Himanshu - You should explain what you've tried. People here can be really helpful and friendly, but you have to show that you've done some research on the topic yourself. It also helps tell us where you're at so that we can provide you an answer that's closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: @rekire - Not correct. Remote XUL is a very real concept, and there are a few examples of this in the wild. However, that XUL code doesn't have the same permissions as local XUL code would, like what's in an extension or XULApp.

Comment: Your XUL application has logic in javascript, so you can send JSONP request. On server-side, that JSONP can be return by php, for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is a scripting language. In general, when we think of scripting languages and the markup that they generate, we tend to mainly think about HTML.

However, scripting languages can be used to generate *any* type of content, such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript, XML, and even XUL.

In this case, you want your Web server to serve up PHP as content-type "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml". Some webservers won't recognize this mime type by default. If yours doesn't, then you'll need to add that mime type to your server configuration.

> If you build a XUL file along with this tutorial and put it onto a web server, you need to configure your web server to specify the content type of XUL files as application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml. For Apache, you can do this by adding the following line to your mime.types file:
>
> **application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml .xul**
>
> ---
>
> Alternately, add this line to your httpd.conf file or, if the Apache server is configured to allow it, to the .htaccess file in the directory from which the XUL file is served:
>
> **AddType application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml .xul**
>
> Then restart your web server.
>
> ---
>
> With PHP you can send the mime-type with the header() function.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml');
?>
<!-- XUL markup starts here -->
```

The last point is important. Remember that in most cases, we serve HTML with PHP, and most servers do a good job of recognizing that the content type is text/html. In your case, you may want to explicitly set the content type header yourself, as done in the above example.

See [Using Remote XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_remote_xul) for more details and information.

Comment: +1 Great answer, but the correct content type is like in your ressource `application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml`.